# How to Change the currentUrl id in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to change the id property of currentUrl object in my component .What I want to achieve is that once the id gets changed , it should fetch the appropriate data from the id . I am currently getting the below error .

"**Cannot assign to read only property 'id' of object '[object Object]'**"

Can anybody help me fix this?

```
addBranch(id){
      this.currentUrl = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params;
      console.log(this.currentUrl.id); // Currently the id is undefined
      this.currentUrl.id = id; //Cannot assign to read only property 'id' of object '[object Object]'
      window.location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this via the angular Router. First, inject it into your Component:

```
constructor( private router: Router )
{}
```

(if you already have an existing constructor, extend it accordingly).

Now you can just use `this.router.navigate(['/your-desired-route', id]);` instead of

```
this.currentUrl.id = id;
window.location.reload();
```

This will not cause a full page reload, but just set the correct URL and trigger anything that is required to process the route change (like determining the correct component to handle the request), thus avoiding an unnecessary reinitialization of angular.